# Trouble filtering results from elasticsearch using Ajax

Tags: ajax, elasticsearch, amplifyjs

I am using Amplify to do my Ajax calls to elasticsearch, however I am having issues filtering my results.  Since I am passing everything as a URL I am unsure how to format it. 
The following returns 4 results when I pass firstName:John as the searchCriteria.

```
self.url = "http://leServer:lePort/people/person/_search?q=" + self.searchCriteria;
```

If I have firstName:John&lastName:Smith  it returns 6 results because there are 2 smith records with a first name other than John.

If I run the following from my command prompt I get one result which is to be expected.

```
curl -XGET "http://leServer:lePort/people/person/_search?pretty=true" -d "{
  \"query\": {
    \"filtered\": {
      \"query\": {
        \"text\": {
          \"firstName\": \"John\"
        }
      },
      \"filter\": {
        \"query\": {
          \"text\": {
            \"lastName\": \"Smith\"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}"
```

I tried using the following as my Ajax call however it does not return anything.  I also tried with the `\"` that the curl request had.

```
self.url = "http://leServer:lePort/people/person/_search?" +"-d"+"{query:{filtered:{query:{text:{firstName:John}},filter:{query:{text:{lastName:Smith}}}}}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be url encoded `+firstName:John +lastName:Smith`. By the way, it might be a bad idea to expose your elasticsearch server to outside world.

Comment: I tried using _search?q=lastName:Smith+firstName:John and it returned 6 results, 4 with a first name John, and 2 with last name Smith.  Also about the outside exposure, its an intranet site.

Comment: The default operator for queries is OR, you can change it by adding default_operator=AND to URL or by adding `+` before each field. Try this: `?q=%2blastName:Smith+%2bfirstName:John`

Comment: That worked perfectly. However I am curious why I need to use both + and %2b, while ++ does not give the desired results.